# Foobar2000: any way to query whether a song is in a specific playlist?

Tags: foobar2000, query

In Foobar2000, I would like to make an autoplaylist that only shows songs that are not currently in another specific (manual) playlist.

Is there any way to query for this?

I imagine the query to look something like:

```
%rating% GREATER 3 AND NOT IN playlist1 OR playlist2
```

The ultimate goal would be to sort all my favorite music into two categories and to have an easy way to do so in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do exactly what you want without creating a custom plugin.

However, my suggestion would be to add a custom metadata field to mark the files from your existing "manual" playlist. That way you can easily create two autoplaylists - one to represent the old one and a new one that doesn't overlap the other.

Note that this assumes that your playlist is a Foobar playlist and not a generic (M3U etc.) playlist

- To add the metadata field, select and right-click the relevant files from your original list and choose **Properties**. In the *Metadata* tab, right-click and select **Add new field...**

  [image: How to add metadata]
- Set *Field name* to be *FAVOURITE*
- Set a single value which will be *True*
- To add your new auto playlists, choose **Library-> Search**.
- Enter the following filter string for you manual playlist:

  ```
  FAVOURITE IS "True"
  ```
- Click the **...** button and choose **Create Autoplaylist**
- For your other autoplaylist you need something like the following:

  ```
  FAVOURITE MISSING AND RATING GREATER 3
  ```

Alternatively you could use a numeric value for the custom field in order to allow more than two playlists.

Comment: Ooh, that's a great idea. Will give that a go. Thank you!

Comment: Hope you understand I had to let the bounty run its course, but since your answer is working out fine I'll naturally award it to you. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded a component for foobar2k called "Quick Tagger" or foo_quicktag.

Within Tools > Tagging ? Quick Tagger I have setup a custom Field known as "Rating" with the Values "1; 2; 3; 4; 5"

Within a playlist you can right-click a song and under Quick Tagger you will see Rating with a sub-menu of your options--in this case 1 through 5.

To see the fancy rating visuals tithin Display -> Default User Interface -> Playlist View setup a Custom Column known as "Rating" with the Pattern "$if(%rating%,$repeat(o,%rating%),x)"

Replace o with the character you want to fill up your 1-5 rating. I have replaced o with a more bullet-type character.  Replace "x" with anything you want for when a song is not rated. This could be a single bullet or an entirely different character to indicate rating unavailable.

What you are now left with is within a PlayList you will see each song has a Ratings column with a properly assigned Rating tag.  Start having fun and tagging your songs.

Now I wanna make a playlist after I got a bunch of songs. I want all Songs with 3 or higher stars. I type "RATING GREATER 2" into my music library Filter and it shows only songs I have rated 3 or higher. I add all this to a playlist and start having fun.

Good luck!

Comment: I already have ratings set up through the "Playback Statistics" (or `foo_playcount`) module, but thanks for the tip.

Comment: So I have the following column set up: `$if(%rating%,$repeat(★,%rating%)$repeat(☆,$sub(5,%rating%)),?)`
That way it will always be five characters wide, _if_ a rating is provided. The question mark could be substituted for five hollow stars if desired.

Comment: I then assigned keyboard shortcuts to make rating tracks a bit more convenient. Another option would be to add toolbar buttons to do that.